# How to store and load the connections of jsplumb (Using AngularJS and jsPlumb)

Tags: angularjs, jsplumb

Can pls anyone help me out how to store and load the connections, and anchor placements jsplumb and anjular js.

pls check the below image link 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC1PR.jpg).

1st one is the image without connections, second one with connections.

when i reload the page, still i need to get the connections in same places

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a connection is established, "**connection**"([SOURCE](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/events.html#evt-connection)) event is triggered. You need to store the connection endpoints details in that triggered function so that you can retrieve them later.

First make sure that you have set proper id for your endpoints. You can manually set at time of endpoint creation as:

```
var e0 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("div1",{uuid:"div1_ep1"}),  // You can also set uuid based on element it is placed on
 e1 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("div2",{uuid:"div2_ep1"});
```

Now bind the **connection** event where you will store the established connections info:

```
var uuid, index=0; // Array to store the endpoint sets.
jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(ci) {
    var eps = ci.connection.endpoints;
    console.log(eps[0].getUuid() +"->"+ eps[1].getUuid()); // store this information in 2d-Array or any other format you wish
    uuid[index][0]=eps[0].getUuid(); // source endpoint id
    uuid[index++][1]=eps[1].getUuid(); // target endpoint id
    }
});
```

You can convert the array information to JSON format and store at the server side. When page is refreshed you need to retrieve the JSON data and restore the connection. For connecting the endpoints based on uuid make use of:

```
jsPlumb.connect({ uuids:["div1_ep1","div2_ep1"] });
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajnWU/10/) for making connections based on endpoints.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to store this "console.log(eps[0].id +"->"+ eps[1].id);" values in 2d-array. but im unable to store. can you pls help me out...

Comment: @user3876350 I didn't mean to store the entire statement, just store the values eps[0].getUuid() and eps[1].getUuid() into the array.

Comment: Hi Pruthvi i've tried to store the values in array, but each connections are loaded in separate array, how to store all the connections in single array,

Comment: Include your code in jsFiddle and provide the link to help you better!

Comment: hi pls check line no - 225 in javascript block http://jsfiddle.net/lakimathan/5y2ytqvp/1/

Comment: You need to make "uuid" as global variable since it will store all connection endpoint sets. Check the updated answer. Also make sure that you set proper UUID for endpoints during their creation.